# Как подключиться к БД Oracle в PyCharm

Tags: python, oracle

Не могу понять что делать.
Прошу помощи

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\app\gm\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@DESKTOP-K1VD24O')
cursor = conn.cursor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('cx_Oracle')
    print(conn.version)
```

Comment: версия оракла 18XE

Comment: Ошибка говорит сама за себя, и даже ссылка на инструкцию есть.  А что конкретно вам осталось не понятно?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Причина: битность Python и библотеки клиента не совпадают.

Судя по пути, указанному в сообшении об ошибке, найдена библиотека встронного в БД клиента и его битность, как и самой БД - 64.

Необходимо установить [32-bit Windows Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html) (для 18c подойдёт 19.9.0.0.0 Basic Package). Имя каталога, куда будет распакован архив, необходимо, *что предпочтительней*, указать явно при инициализации клиента, или добавить в переменную окружения `PATH`:

```
import cx_Oracle as cxora

cxora.init_oracle_client (lib_dir='d:/app/oracle/instantclient_19_6')

conn = cxora.connect ('connect_string')
print('Connected', conn.version, 'client', cxora.clientversion ())
```

У меня выводит:

> Connected 19.3.0.0.0 client (19, 6, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: скачал клиент по предоставленной ссылке, создал переменную в PATH (в user variables и в system variables прописал), вставил ваш код и поправил путь расположения клиента... Ошибка не пропала.

Comment: Попробуйте без PATH  в init_oracle_client прописать. Если ошибка останется, добавте как PS полное сообщение об ошибке в вопрос (или просто комментарий).

Comment: удалил path.. без изминенийюю пише: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gm/PycharmProjects/Oracle/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    cxora.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='c:/app/gm/product/oracle/instantclient_19_9')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: import cx_Oracle as cxora

cxora.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='c:/app/gm/product/oracle/instantclient_19_9')

conn = cxora.connect('connect_string')
print('Connected', conn.version, 'client', cxora.clientversion())

Comment: @nk.nkt Путь верный? Ошибка изменилась: The specified module could not be found. То есть, драйвер не  находит oci.dll по пути, который вы написали.

Comment: вернул переменные патч, переписал вот так:    import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hr@ XEPDB1')
cursor = conn.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('cx_Oracle')
    print(conn.version)   Программа запускается и ошибка не происходит, но принт инфо нету

Comment: ... путь верный.. копипаст

Comment: @nk.nkt Если через PATH работает, то через init тоже должно.  Попробуйте print без if.